# Video encryption by Crypto.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, cryptojs

How to encrypt and decrypt video and audio streaming url by crypto.js? 
This line of code :

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("#string#", "#theKey#");
```

require  data as string.

So what can I do? I just have a video URL.

Comment: so, the url itself is encrypted, or the video stream is encrypted?

Comment: This code just encrypt the url text!.  We have to find a way to read video data packets from sucket as string.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just want to encrypt a video stream url and send it to specific destination.

Comment: If you're using only browser symmetric encryption you need the exact same key at the server and the client. If you send the encryption key from the server to the client or the other way around you need to encrypt your symmetric encryption key. The easiest way to do this would be to use TLS. If you use TLS, then the data as well as key are encrypted, so you don't need to encrypt it yourself. This doesn't provide any security, just a little bit of obfuscation. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as put the url in a variable, you will have to listen to a stream, & when you receive data you will have to download it and encrypt it after.

Just check at ffmpeg node_module if you have specific video stream url (m3u format) or just request if you have a file video url